# How to iterate through a listview and assign the main item and subitems texts onto iterated buttons

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to grab the texts of each row of a ListView and assiging it to the 
iterated tiles/buttons. The code I written unfortunately take only the last row and prints it onto all
the iterated Tiles. (the Tiles are DevExpress - third party comps. by the way. but thats not the focus here)

For example. The listview contains the following two rows (it may be more);

```
Name | Country | City
---------------------------
Sam  |  Japan  | Tokyo
Dexter | Italy | Rome
```

thus what I seek is the ability to print onto the iterated tiles/buttons in this way:

FIRST TILE's TEXT:
Sam
Japan 
Tokyo

SECOND TILE's TEXT:
Dexter
Italy
Rome

This is my code:

```
Dim strTileInfo As String = Nothing

    For Each tile As TileItem In TheTileControl.Items 'My iteration code through the tiles/buttons

        strTileInfo = Nothing
        tile.Text = Nothing

        'My attempt to assign each row of the ListView main item and subitem texts 
        'i.e. Each row to each button
        For i = 0 To ListView.Items.Count - 1
            strTileInfo = ListView.Items(i).Text & vbCrlf & ListView.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text
            tile.Text = strTileInfo
        Next

    Next
```

I will be very grateful for your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Is the count of tiles equal to the count of items in the listview? By the way, your issue is because you loop through all the list items for each tile and always set the tile caption to the value of the last list item...

Comment: hello Robin. I really am trying to figure it out thru out the day. I will be glad if anyone can support me with code. I keep reading thru trying to assess the logic but still not resolving it and time is not on my side. An example at this stage will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The code take only the last row and prints it in all the iterated Tiles, because for each Tile you cross the ListView to the last element, and the latter is assigned under. Try this code :

```
Dim strTileInfo As String = Nothing

Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each tile As TileItem In TheTileControl.Items
    strTileInfo = Nothing
    tile.Text = Nothing

    If i < ListView.Items.Count Then
        strTileInfo = ListView.Items(i).Text & vbCrLf & ListView.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text
        tile.Text = strTileInfo
        i += 1
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Glad to help you! If this solves your problem, remember to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you too :)